# Way to move files in bash and rename copied file automatically without overwriting an existing file

Tags: macos, bash, unix, scripting, file-rename

I'm doing some major restructuring of large numbers of directories with tons of jpgs, some of which my have the same name as files in other directories.  I want to move / copy files to alternate directories and have bash automatically rename them if the name matches another file in that directory (renaming `IMG_238.jpg` to `IMG_238_COPY1.jpg`, `IMG_238_COPY2.jpg`, etc), instead of overwriting the existing file.

I've set up a script that takes jpegs and moves them to a new directory based on exif data. The final line of the script that moves one jpg is: `mv -n "$JPEGFILE" "$DIRNAME"`

I'm using the -n option because I don't want to overwrite files, but now I have to go and manually sort through the ones that didn't get moved / copied.  My GUI does this automatically...  Is there a relatively simple way to do this in bash?

(In case it matters, I'm using bash 3.2 in Mac OSX Lion).

Comment: What distro are you using, or does this need to be cross-distro?

Comment: I'm using Mac OSX Lion with bash 3.2. I'll update my question.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [fdupes](http://premium.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html) - it can help you get rid of duplicate files so any files that you have left over "unmoved" due to same name are really different files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to do it

```
# strip path, if any
fname="${JPEGFILE##*/}"
[ -f "$DIRNAME/$fname" ] && {
    n=1
    while [ -f "$DIRNAME/${fname%.*}_COPY${n}.${fname##*.}" ] ; do
        let n+=1
    done
    mv "$JPEGFILE" "$DIRNAME/${fname%.*}_COPY${n}.${fname##*.}"
} || mv "$JPEGFILE" "$DIRNAME"
```

EDIT: Improved.

Comment: You can safely drop the first ``[ -f "$DIRNAME/$JPEGFILE" ]``

Comment: You can also safely drop the tailing or ``|| mv "$JPEGFILE" ...``

Comment: @holygeek: Dropping the leading test and alternate mv will change the semantics. We don't want to add `_COPY${n}` in all cases, only as needed. The `&& mv` vs. `; mv` is quite right, I got rid of it on my first reread.

Comment: Sorry my answer had this for the while condition: ``while [ -f "$DIRNAME/$JPEGFILE" ]; do ...`` before your answer popped in so I thought I'd suggest to simplify your answer instead of posting a similiar one. By the way that ``mv "$fname" "$DIR..."`` looks wrong to me if ``$JPEGFILE`` had path.

Comment: @holygeek: You're right, `$fname` was incorrect there. It should have been `$JPEGFILE`. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [downloading](http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt) and seeing if Ubuntu/Debian's Perl-based `rename` works. It has `sed`-style functionality. Quoth the man page (on my system, but the script should be the same one as linked):

> "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified
>      as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression
>      which is expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some of
>      the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the
>      expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the
>      command line, filenames will be read via standard input.
>
> For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the
>     extension, you might say
>
> ```
>     rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
> ```
>
> To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use
>
> ```
>     rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
> ```